# change winrt datepicker selected item background color

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to change selected item background in winrt DatePicker

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF367DB2" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF367DB2" />        
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Added this code in StandardStyles.xaml change it but in all pages in the application but i want to change it only in this page.

Comment: Are you using Windows 8.1's [`DatePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn308514.aspx) or creating your own using `ComboBox`?

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/packages/WinRT-DatePicker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to create custom style for `ComboBox`, below given is default style. Change the `SolidColorBrush` resources in the style according to your requirement. Then apply customized `ComboBox` style to `DatePicker` style.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="MyComboBox">
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,0" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxBorderThemeBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxBorderThemeThickness}" />
  <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
  <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <CarouselPanel />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedBorderThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="FocusedPressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedHighlightThemeBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
              <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
              <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                <Storyboard>
                  <SplitOpenThemeAnimation OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" ContentTargetName="ScrollViewer" ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" ContentTranslationOffset="0" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset}" OpenedLength="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight}" ClosedLength="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownClosedHeight}" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <SplitCloseThemeAnimation OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" ContentTargetName="ScrollViewer" ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" ContentTranslationOffset="40" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset}" ContentTranslationDirection="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.SelectedItemDirection}" OpenedLength="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight}" ClosedLength="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownClosedHeight}" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Border x:Name="Background" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
          <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedHighlightThemeBrush}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" />
          <Border x:Name="HighlightBackground" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusedBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" />
          <Rectangle x:Name="Highlight" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBoxSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" />
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
          <TextBlock x:Name="DropDownGlyph" Text="" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,0,6,4" Foreground="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowForegroundThemeBrush}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}" FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
          <Popup x:Name="Popup">
            <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupBackgroundThemeBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupBorderThemeThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
              <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Foreground="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupForegroundThemeBrush}" VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                <ItemsPresenter />
              </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
          </Popup>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>


xmlns:dt="using:WinRTDatePicker"

<Style TargetType="dt:DatePicker" x:Key="MyDatePicker">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="dt:DatePicker">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="_DayOptions"
                              Style="{StaticResource MyComboBox}"
                              Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="_MonthOptions"
                              Style="{StaticResource MyComboBox}"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="_YearOptions"
                              Style="{StaticResource MyComboBox}"
                              Grid.Column="2" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<dt:DatePicker Style="{StaticResource MyDatePicker}" />
```

Comment: i can't apply combobox style to datePicker

WinRT information: Cannot apply a Style with TargetType 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBoxItem' to an object of type 'WinRTDatePicker.DatePicker'. [Line: 251 Position: 105]

Comment: I forget to add key in `DatePicker` style. Please check updated answer. Set `TargetType` as `ComboBox` not `ComboBoxItem`.